# Color to 12 shades of Grayscale conversion & Grid overlay

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color-conversion, grids, grayscale

Thanks for reading my post. I would like to create a grid drawing, like the ones done by Chuck Close.  This uses a system where an existing photo is transposed/painted by hand to a much larger canvas, using a grid system, so that the resulting painting/drawing is photorealistic.
The system uses a numbered grid overlaid on the original photo, which is used to transpose the colour in each grid cell onto a larger canvas which also has a grid overlaid on it. It is kind of like a “paint by numbers” process.

I am planning on doing this with a ‘black and white photo’ - really grayscale, but with only 12 shades ranging from white though to black which align with the markers I want to use, which are a ‘cool grey’ set of 12 copic markers. I can find the RGB values for them here: C-0 to C-10 plus the black “100” marker.  https://www.swatchtool.com/copic
Markers are here: http://www.copicmarker.com.au/copic-marker-set-12-cool-grey

So, I would like to know how I can convert a black and white photo, preferably in photoshop.
to:
Have an 18” longest side (this is the maximum size my local print shop can do)
Convert to a 12 colour greyscale
Overlay a grid (in a colour that stands out, perhaps red)
Number each grid cell from 1-12 corresponding to the shade of gray
Thanks for your help

Comment: Welcome to GDSE. Would you mind posting an example image rather than making people search for one. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, it could be any color portrait. I didnt think an example was necessary and didn't mean to make people search for one... [link](https://image.slidesharecdn.com/year9artportraitureandthealteregoschemeofwork-150804113331-lva1-app6892/95/year-9-art-portraiture-and-the-alter-ego-scheme-of-work-12-638.jpg?cb=1438688173)

Comment: Gradient map. You have to be carrful with this though the color spread of panatone markers are different from your monitor.